# How do you access multi-dimension array by N array of index element-wise?

Tags: julia

Suppose we have

```
A = [1 2; 3 4]
```

In numpy, the following syntax will produce

```
A[[1,2],[1,2]] = [1,4]
```

But, in julia, the following produce a permutation which output

```
A[[1,2],[1,2]] = [1 2; 3 4]
```

Is there a concise way to achieve the same thing as numpy without using for loops?

Comment: If those are alements on the diagonal you can also try ` LinearAlgebra.diag(A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Bogumil said, you probably want to use `CartesianIndex`. But if you want to get your result from supplying the vectors of indices for each dimensions, as in your Python `[1,2],[1,2]` example, you need to `zip` these indices first:

```
julia> A[CartesianIndex.(zip([1,2], [1,2]))]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 4
```

How does this work? `zip` traverses both vectors of indices at the same time (like a [zipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper)) and returns an iterator over the tuples of indices:

```
julia> zip([1,2],[1,2]) # is a lazy iterator
zip([1, 2], [1, 2])

julia> collect(zip([1,2],[1,2])) # collect to show all the tuples
2-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 1)
 (2, 2)
```

and then `CartesianIndex` turns them into cartesian indices, which can then be used to get the corresponding values in `A`:

```
julia> CartesianIndex.(zip([1,2],[1,2]))
2-element Vector{CartesianIndex{2}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1)
 CartesianIndex(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

To get what you want I would use `CartesianIndex` like this:

```
julia> A[CartesianIndex.([(1,1), (2,2)])]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 4
```

or

```
julia> A[[CartesianIndex(1,1), CartesianIndex(2,2)]]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 4
```